# Fetch list of restaurants in user's proximity using Firebase-GeoFire

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have a list of restaurants each of which has a fixed location which is stored in GeoFire. Now I want to display the restaurants within a fixed radius of user location. How can I achieve this using GeoFire. The documentation here, https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geofiresetkeyorlocations-location mostly suggests solutions in which geofire 'keys' are moving which are handled using key_entered, key_exited etc. But I'm not able to figure out how to access the keys in proximity.

My controller code looks like:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
var geoFire = new GeoFire(ref.child("geofire"));
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
$scope.rest= [];
$scope.filteredRest = [];
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
  center: [position.coords.latitude,  position.coords.longitude],
  radius: 15
});
geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
  console.log(key);
  $scope.filteredRest.push(key);
});
geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
  geoQuery.cancel();
});
console.log($scope.filteredRest);
```

The key is printed on console but is not pushed to filteredRest array.

I'm looking to achieve 'Example usage' in following link:
https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#example-usage

There are similar questions but most of them are in ios/swift and the answers are not very informative. I'm using GeoFire-JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `key_entered` event will also fire for non-moving keys. It will fire "straight away" for all keys in the range and then for every key entering the range. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Okay but will this let me access all the keys for which the event has been fired? Not exactly sure what a GeoCallbackRegistration is which is returned.

Comment: You'll have to build a collection of keys by hooking `key_entered`. If you want to know when all the *initial* keys have been fired, you can hook the `ready` event: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback

Comment: I'm able to access individual keys through key_entered but I'm not able to store the keys as a collection. Can you point to any example? I think the issue is due to asynchronous nature of firebase.

Comment: That indeed seems like. At this stage it is up to you to  provide a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. Providing a link to an example is off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle when all the initial keys are synchronized, put the code into the `ready` handler. For example, say you want to print all the initial keys:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
var geoFire = new GeoFire(ref.child("geofire"));
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
$scope.rest= [];
$scope.filteredRest = [];
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
  center: [position.coords.latitude,  position.coords.longitude],
  radius: 15
});
geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
  $scope.filteredRest.push(key);
});
geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
  geoQuery.cancel();
  console.log($scope.filteredRest);
});
```

Comment: That was easy! Thanks for the help! You da MVP!

Comment: Hey guys, I don't mean to be rude but I am trying to do something quite similar and I can't sort it out, could you take a look at my post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462088/geofire-doesnt-return-the-result

Comment: Is it possible in Javascript?  To search keys (list of keys) of near by static(fixed) locations - which are pre-added in firebase datastore.

Note: not using 'key_entered' because 'key_entered' only fires when new or position updated. What about previously added locations but coming under given radius.

How is it possible??